# Split challenges on an array formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, substitution

I am trying to split the following standard:
This is column B

```
{"Dom":"DSQR","ID":"987","Name":"Stephen Jones"}
{"Dom":"DSQR","ID":"987","Name":"Tania Dewes"}
```

The formula is as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="", "", TRIM(SPLIT(B2:B,M2))))
```

M2 cell is:

```
ID":"
```

Result is:
[image]

Could you explain why Stephen Jones shows correctly and Tania doesn't?
I'd like the split to work like it does on the first line.

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A1:A, ":,", 1), "[\{\}""]", )))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[\{\}""]|ID", ), ":,", 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: @Jerome answer updated

Comment: While it works here, I don't think json can or should be parsed like this. Plenty of things could go wrong.  Just for eg, If `Name` is `Tania, Dewes`, it'll fail.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there's none of `ID":"` in `Stephen Jones`, while there's a `D` in `Tania Dewes`. Suggest using a proper parser, like a custom function to parse JSON.